# How to use two Bluetooth adapters in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have checked two different Bluetooth adapters (one with UART interface and other with USB interface Bluetooth dongle) separately in Android Lollipop 5.0. I have done this with kernel changes and HAL changes. (UART HAL and USB support HAL in libbt).

Now I want to know, Is it possible to have multiple Bluetooth adapters working, i.e in my case, I want to use both the UART interfaced TI's  bluetooth as well USB dongle-Bluetooth simultaneously. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is not support yet. the Adapter here actually means the controller or the RF, now since you have two RFs, the Adapter does not know who should operate. however you can modify the code, e.g. add the index to make it support two RF's but this is lot of work to do.

Another option is that made another bluetooth device e.g. the USB device, to a neutral device, you also run your own stack, and add JNI and services, to make it does not act with the original adapter.

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly the role of RF here? So far I have understanding that we concentrate on Bluetooth adapters  and adapter firmware take care of that RF.

Comment: sorry the RF(radio frequency) here means the interface of your Bluetooth dongle, i.e. your USB dongle and UART dongle.

Comment: It may not the best method that you extend the usage of Adapter, you may need change log of code. So you just create another dummy or an virtual adapter, i.e.only include the function your apps need.

Comment: How I know or where one can check this if support for multiple adapters were added/implemented for Android?